# Unique password to access a section site

Tags: users, user-registration, user-access

I am working on a wordpress site. I am selling a digital course on it. Users interested in the course will pay locally via bank and send me payment details.

So after I confirm their payment I will like to add their email and phone number to database. I don't know about also generate a unique code like password to append the email and phone number. So they can enter their email/phone and the password I gave to them to enter part of the site where they have access to the course materials.

Just like am going to manually create the user login by by self so they can access the page.
Am just a part time beginner WordPress developer  please explain answers comprehensively.

Answer (score 1):

There are dozens of ways to achive this. While your approach might work for a low amount of users, it propably is too much work to deal with hundrets or even thousands of users.

That's why I would highly recommend an automated approach, where most of the user handling is done by WordPress.

However, for a low amount of users, I would simply use one of these Plugins:

- Nav Menu Roles
- WP Members
- WP User Manager

Then create a user role like "full-members" or "paid-members". Let all members register, and give them the same basic user level, when somebody did pay, simply change his user-role from "basic" to "paid-users". Sure, you need to create a page, where only paid users have access to.

This process is still half-automatic and not scalable to, because you have to edit every user manually.

In case your amount of users is growing and you need to scale your application, I would look out for something like a PayPal-plugin, because you would need a connection to your bank-account in order to check if your money is transferred or not and then trigger a follow-up actions based on the first event.